# Direct sum of non-generate representations of a C*-algebra is itself non-degenerate

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra. Let $\{(H_{\lambda}, \varphi_{\lambda})\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ be a family of non-degenerate representations of $A$.

Let $\oplus_{\lambda \in \Lambda} H_{\lambda}$ denote the algebraic direct sum, i.e. subspace of the direct product of the $H_{\lambda}$'s where at most finitely many coordinates are non-zero. This is clearly an inner product space with respect to the canonical inner product:

$\langle (x_{\lambda}), (y_{\lambda}) \rangle := \sum_{\lambda} \langle x_{\lambda}, y_{\lambda} \rangle$.

Define $\varphi:A \to B(\oplus_{\lambda \in \Lambda} H_{\lambda})$ by
$\varphi(a)((x_{\lambda})) = (\varphi_{\lambda}(a)(x_{\lambda}))$. It can be checked that
$\varphi$ is a well-defined algebra homomorphism. Since each $\varphi_{\lambda}$ is a * - homomorphism between $C^*$-algebras, they are all norm-decreasing.

Let $H$ denote the Hilbert space completion of $\oplus_{\lambda \in \Lambda} H_{\lambda}$. Then we can extend $\varphi$ to the map $\tilde{\varphi}:A \to B(H)$. It can be checked that $\tilde{\varphi}$ is a * - homomorphism and hence $(H, \tilde{\varphi})$ is a representation of $A$.

So, my question is: Is $(H, \tilde{\varphi})$ also a non-degenerate representation of $A$?

Comment: Yes of course. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show your attempts and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is $(H,φ)$  also a non-degenerate representation of $A$?

Yes. One rather direct way of seeing this is to consider an approximate unit $\{a_j\}$ in $A$. As the net $(\varphi(a_j))$ is a monotone increasing net of selfadjoint operators, it has a strong limit. The non-degeneracy makes it easy to check that $\varphi(a_j)\to 1$. And this implies that $\varphi$ is non-degenerate.

Comment: The truly direct proof would be simpler, and the OP should anyway show some work before being given any.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Martin! I tried to prove it directly by starting with a $y \in H \setminus {0}$ and then approximating it with a vector in the algebraic direct sum. But that obviously doesn't work as you can have a sequence of non-zero vectors converging to zero! The idea of using the fact that a net of increasing hermitian operators bounded above is strongly convergent and in this case $\varphi(a_i) \to 1$ seems pretty non-trivial to me. It just didn't occur to me! Thanks again!